# Overloading the '-' operator

Tags: c++

Currently I'm writing a program that has a section to determine the difference in days between two dates, but by overloading the minus operator.

I'm currently staring at my screen drawing a complete blank. I have some fleeting thoughts in my head but they are exactly that, fleeting.

What's to happen in the main.cpp is that there are going to be two variables, for instance `beethovenDeathDate` and `beethovenBirthDate` that will be subtracted to determine how long he lived for. Which is something around 22000 days if I recall correctly.

So without further ado, here is my code:

## Date.cpp

```
const std::string Date::MONTH_STRINGS[] = 
{
    "", //one based indexing
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May", 
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
};

const int Date::DAYS_PER_MONTH[] =
{
    0, //one based indexing
    31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
};      

Date::Date(int day, int month, int year) : _year(year), _month(month), _day(day)
{
    isValid();
}

Date::Date()
{
    time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
    _year = now -> tm_year + 1900;
    _month = now -> tm_mon + 1;
    _day = now -> tm_mday;
}

int Date::maxDay(int month, int year)
{
    int ret = DAYS_PER_MONTH[month];
    if(isLeapYear(year) == true && month == 2)
    {
        ++ret;
    }
    return ret;
}

void Date::addDay(bool forward)
{
    if(forward)
    {
        if(_day < maxDay(_month, _year))
        {
            ++_day;
        }
        else
        {
            _day = MIN_DAY;
            ++_month;
            if(_month > MAX_MONTH)
            {
                _month = MIN_MONTH;
                ++_year;
            }    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(_day <= MIN_DAY)
        {
            --_month;
            if(_month < MIN_MONTH)
            {
                _month = MAX_MONTH;
                --_year;
            } 
            _day = maxDay(_month, _year);
        }
        else
        {
            --_day;
        }
    }    
}


std::string Date::toString() const
{
    if(isValid() == false)
    {
        return std::string();
    }
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss  << MONTH_STRINGS[_month] << " " << _day << ", " <<  _year;
    return ss.str();            
}    


bool Date::isValid() const
{
    if(_month < MIN_MONTH || _month > MAX_MONTH)
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid date " << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    int daysThisMonth = maxDay(_month, _year);

    if(_day < MIN_DAY || _day > daysThisMonth)
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid date " << std::endl;            
        return false;   
    }
    return true;
}

bool Date::isLeapYear(int year)
{
    if(!(year % 4))
    {
        if(!(year % 100))
        {
            if(!(year % 400))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool Date::isLeapYear() const
{
    return isLeapYear(_year);
}

bool Date::isLeapDay() const
{
    return isLeapDay(_day, _month, _year);
}

bool Date::isLeapDay(int day, int month, int year) 
{
    if(day == 29 &&  month == 2 && isLeapYear(year) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


void Date::addYears(int years)
{
    if(years == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(isLeapDay() && !isLeapDay(_day, _month, _year + years))
    {
        _day = Date::DAYS_PER_MONTH[_month];
    }
    _year += years;
}

void Date::addMonths(int months)    
{
    if(months == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    int deltayears = months / MAX_MONTH;
    int deltamonths = months % MAX_MONTH;
    int newMonth = 0;
    if(months > 0)
    {
        newMonth = (_month + deltamonths) % MAX_MONTH;
        if((_month + deltamonths) > MAX_MONTH)
        {
            ++deltayears;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if((_month + deltamonths) < MIN_MONTH)
        {
            --deltayears;
            newMonth = _month + deltamonths + MAX_MONTH;
        }
        else
        {
            newMonth = _month + deltamonths;
        }       
    }
    if(_day > maxDay(newMonth, _year + deltayears))
    {
        _day = maxDay(newMonth, _year + deltayears);
    }
    _year += deltayears;
    _month = newMonth;

}

void Date::addDays(int days)
{
    if(days == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(days < 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i > days; --i)
        {
            addDay(false);
        }
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < days; ++i)
    {
        addDay(true);
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Date& date)
{
    os << date.toString();
    return os;
}

Date Date::operator+(int days) const
{
    Date ret = *this;
    ret.addDays(days);
    return ret;
}

Date& Date::operator+=(int days)
{
    addDays(days);
    return *this;
}
//This is where I get stumped (the parameters was just one of my failed experiments
Date& Date::operator-(int day, int month, int year)
{
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to subtract days, month, or years from the date? I ask because in your other overloaded arithmetic operators, you only had `days` as a parameter.

Comment: Well the two have different purposes. I am learning out of a book right now, and the "assignment" calls for the overloaded + is only to add two things together, where the - is explicity called to determine the difference in days between the two called variables.

Comment: So if that is the case, you want to take as a parameter a date object and find the difference in days between the 2 dates; as opposed to taking in 3 parameters as you are doing.

Comment: The first "s" in [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/) standards for "short" :)

Comment: Already solved problem: http://boost.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/boost/boost/boost/date_time/date.hpp?view=markup#l139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function can be written either as a member, or as a free function.  The member function signature would look like this:

```
TimeDuration Date::operator-(Date const & rhs) const
```

The free function would look like this:

```
TimeDuration operator-(Date const & lhs, Date const & rhs)
```

`TimeDuration` here is a completely seperate type representing a length of time.  If you want, you could just make it an `int` signifying the number of days, but it would be better, in my opinion, to have a more expressive type for this purpose. Whatever you decide regarding the return type, it doesn't make any sense for the type to be `Date` (and certainly not `Date&`).

A possible (albeit not incredibly efficient) implementation, given that you've already written a function to add a day to a date, would be something like this:

```
if lhs_date comes before rhs_date
    add days to (a copy of) lhs_date until lhs_date == rhs_date
    return the negative of number of days added
if rhs_date comes before lhs_date
    add days to (a copy of) rhs_date until rhs_date == lhs_date
    return the number of days added
else
    return 0
```

Another function you might want (or maybe this is what you actually wanted originally, but your wording doesn't indicate it) is a function which can subtract a length of time from a `Date`.  In that case, the return value would be another `Date` object (but not `Date&`), and the possible signatures would look something like this:

```
Date Date::operator-(TimeDuration rhs) const // member version
Date operator-(Date const & lhs, TimeDuration const & rhs) // non-member version
```

Comment: @AndrewB Exactly -- `lhs - rhs`.

Comment: How would I fill the function? That is mostly what is stumping me at the moment, however getting a proper function is definitely a step in the right direction. Also, I'm fairly new to C++ so where is `TimeDuration` coming from in your bottom scenario?

Comment: @AndrewB You can normalize everything in terms of days and perform the difference.

Comment: @AndrewB: You wrote a function to add a day. It should be fairly simple to reverse the logic, making a function that subtracts a day. Repeat that for however many days make up the duration. Not the most efficient solution, but I'll leave the optimization up to you.  As for `TimeDuration`, it doesn't exist, yet.  It is up to you to define.  Like I said, you could just use an `int` (representing the number of days) in its place, but I prefer types that are more expressive.  If you just use an `int`, you have to document what that `int` stands for.  With a type called `TimeDuration`, you don't.

Comment: @AndrewB: Note that the `TimeDuration` class may be nothing more than a wrapper around an `int` representing the number of days, but that is an implementation detail that the user need not be concerned with.

Comment: The member function versions should be declared `const`.

Comment: In my example I used `beethovenDeathDate` and `beethovenBirthDate` so what I think would be best is to take the data given by `beethovenDeathDate` which is March 26, 1827 in case you were curious, and turn it into days. This is what is stumping me, after that comparing the two is simple. Also, this exercise doesn't take user input.

Comment: @AndrewB: I don't know what you mean by "turn it into days".  A Date is a specific point in time (i.e. *when?*).  "days" is a duration of time (i.e. *how long?*).  They are two seperate concepts.  You cannot turn one into the other.  However, given a particular reference date (e.g. January 1st, the year 1 B.C.E), you can represent a date by its distance from that reference date (which would be a duration).  Is that what you mean?

Comment: I do suppose I'm not wording this very correctly. What I am looking for is a Date (ie, September 9, 2013) to be compared to another date (ie, September 9, 2012) and for it to output the amount of days between the two (in this case, 365). Then it would return the number of days that is just calculated.

Comment: @AndrewB: I'm pretty sure I understood all that from the original question, and my words are failing me if I haven't answered it. Besides writing all the code for you (and I'm not accusing you of asking for that), I really don't know how to make this more clear.  Perhaps someone with better explanatory powers than I will come along.

Comment: I think I just need to step away from the code for a few minutes and think about what you've said and try and implement it in pseudocode instead of beating a dead horse. Thank you very much for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
//This is where I get stumped (the parameters was just one of my failed experiments
TimeDuration& Date::operator-(Date const & d1)
{
    // ... processing ...
    // this - d1;
}
```

and call it as:

```
Date d1 = new Date(20, 01, 2013);
TimeDuration duration = d1 - (new const Date(20, 01, 1922));
// Calculate no. of days or years using duration
```

> The logic is as follows:
>
> 1. Pass two `Date` objects (first could be implicit) to the overloading function and return `TimeDuration`
> 2. To invoke this operator, you may create a `Date` object with the data that you have, instead of passing each value separately.
>
> Please check for exact syntax.

Comment: `Date d1 = new Date(...)` ? What is this? Not C++, certainly.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, you're right. That is why I have mentioned at the end of my answer to check for exact syntax. The solution that I have provided is not an exact copy-paste solution this is just to guide the asker to the correct logic that should go in the implementation. Please let me know if you find anything wrong with the logic.